# Unable to get Hibernate to create schema

Tags: hibernate

How do I get Hibernate to create the database structure for me? Following is a snippet from my applicationContext.xml file:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.application.model" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Though i have specified the hbm2ddl.auto property as create, Hibernate is not creating the schema for me. When i use a call to session.save() to save an object to the database, i get an error as follows:

```
 com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid object name 'Person'.
```

Here is my call to session.save()

```
public void createNewPerson(final String personName, final int personAge)
{
    final Person person = new Person();
    person.setName(personName);
    person.setAge(personAge);
    final Session session = this.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(person);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
}
```

Model class

```
@Entity
public class Person
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    private String name;

    private int age;

    //getters and setters excluded
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work by using

```
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto
```

instead of

```
hbm2ddl.auto
```